# Browser address bar displays #[object%20Object] when clicking the menubar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, address-bar

I found that if I click one of the sections in menubar, the browser address bar displays `#[object%20Object]`. But it didn't influence `scroll-to-section`.

Partial code at reference:

```html
<li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#top" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#users">Evaluations</a></li>
<li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
$('.scroll-to-section a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').on('click', function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width < 991) {
          $('.menu-trigger').removeClass('active');
          $('.header-area .nav').slideUp(200);
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top) + 1
        }, 700);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
      
      //smoothscroll
      $('.scroll-to-section a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(document).off("scroll");
          
          $('.scroll-to-section a').each(function () {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
          })
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var target = this.hash;
          menu = target;
          target = $(this.hash);
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
              scrollTop: (target.offset().top) + 1
          }, 500, 'swing', function () {
              window.location.hash = target;
              $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
          });
      });
  });
```

I tried to update jQuery, but it didn't work.

[Problematic Page](https://class-tools.gq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.hash = target;`

this is the problem. you can't set location.hash to an element. It needs to be an `a name` or `id` in the document. A string. Not an object.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by `var target = this.hash`, you can delete this line.

`target` is overwritten with a jQuery object containing the target element.

Comment: Not exactly. `var target = $('#' + this.hash)` would be fine, assuming we are talking about a name/id  and not a tag name 